# Unable to execute simple java file from windows command line

Tags: java, oop, program-entry-point

Unable to execute this code from windows command line

1. I wrote the code as :

```
package sample;

public class PrivateMain{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println("This is from  main");
    }

}
```

2. I have set the classpath using below commands, but still receiving error as "Could not find or load main class". Am i missing any steps?

```
G:\javaPract>javac PrivateMain.java  

G:\javaPract>java PrivateMain      
Error: Could not find or load main class PrivateMain

G:\javaPract>java sample.PrivateMain 
Error: Could not find or load main class sample.PrivateMain

G:\javaPract>set CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;.

G:\javaPract>echo %CLASSPATH%
G:\javaPract;.

G:\javaPract>javac PrivateMain.java 

G:\javaPract>java PrivateMain      
Error: Could not find or load main class PrivateMain

G:\javaPract>java sample.PrivateMain 
Error: Could not find or load main class sample.PrivateMain

G:\javaPract>
```

3. file contents on G:\javaPract directory:

```
G:\javaPract>dir
 Volume in drive G is Learning
 Volume Serial Number is 008F-C257

 Directory of G:\javaPract

03/21/2023  08:04 AM    <DIR>          .
03/21/2023  08:04 AM    <DIR>          ..
05/17/2023  04:35 PM               280 PrivateMain.java
05/17/2023  04:36 PM               688 PrivateMain.class
```

Comment: Where is your `PrivateMain.class` file located and why is your `PrivateMain.java` file not located inside a directory `sample/`?

Comment: `javac -d . PrivateMain.java;java sample.PrivateMain`

Answer (score 2):

### `java PrivateMain` does not work

That's because your class isn't called that. It's called `sample.PrivateMain`. If you use `java` in a 'I shall give you the name of my class' mode (i.e. not via the `-jar` or `-jmod` launch options), it **has to be** fully qualified.

### `java sample.PrivateMain` does not work

class names are turned into paths by turning dots into slashes and appending `.class`. In other words, if you run `java sample.PrivateMain`, java starts, and checks every dir in the classpath by **appending `sample/PrivateMain.class` to it**. This doesn't find your class because your class isn't in sample/PrivateMain - it's in ./PrivateMain which isn't where java is going to look at all.

### How to fix it

For throwaway projects like this, get rid of the `package` declaration. While you're at it, you can just run `java MyMain.java` - no need to involve `javac`. Once you graduate to more serious projects with multiple source files, and especially, multiple packages, ditch this command line `javac` and `java` stuff and use a build system such as maven or gradle.

If you must, for some strange reason, use a package statement, set up your project like so:

```
cd G:\javaPract
mkdir sample
cd sample
# put your PrivateMain.java file here
javac PrivateMain.java
cd ..
java -cp . sample.PrivateMain
```

key point is, file has to be in `G:\javaPract\sample\PrivateMain.class`, and `G:\javaPract` (**not** `G:\javaPract\sample`!) has to be on the classpath. Then run `java sample.PrivateMain`.

Generally, do not use `CLASSPATH`, just specify with the `-cp` parameter. `CLASSPATH` is a global variable and as a general rule it's bizarre to limit your computer to only run one java application ever.